# Null terminating char pointer

Tags: c

I am completely newbie in C.
I am trying to do simple C function that will split string (char array).

The following code doesn't work properly because I don't know how to terminate char array in the array. There are to char pointers passed in function. One containing original constant char array to be split and other pointer is multidimensional array that will store each split part in separate char array.

Doing the function I encountered obviously lots of hustle, mainly due to my lack of C experience.

I think what I cannot achieve in this function is terminating individual array with '\0'.
Here is the code:

```
void splitNameCode(char *code, char *output);

void splitNameCode(char *code, char *output){

    int     OS = 0; //output string number
    int     loop;
    size_t  s = 1;

    for (loop = 0; code[loop]; loop++){
        if (code[loop] == ':'){ 
            output[OS] = '\0'; // I want to terminate each array in the array
            OS ++;
        }else {
            if (!output[OS]) {
                strncpy(&output[OS], &code[loop], s);
            }else {
                strncat(&output[OS], &code[loop], s);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char output[3][15];
    char str[] = "andy:james:john:amy";
    splitNameCode(str, *output);

    for (int loop = 0; loop<4; loop++) {
        printf("%s\n", output[loop]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say `output` is supposed to be a multidimensional array, namely an array of strings.  But if that is the case, then it should be a `char**`.  Were you given this function signature or do you need help constructing it?

Comment: I would probably need help constructing it. I am not so familiar in C. I tried to use char**, but it got just worse. I have a little clue about pointers, but I am still missing bits and bobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working program for you.  Let me know if you need any explanation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void splitNameCode(char *code, char **output) {
    int i = 0;
    char* token = strtok(code, ":");
    while (token != NULL) {
        output[i++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char* output[4];
    char input[] = "andy:james:john:amy";
    splitNameCode(input, output);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", output[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great, however free function gives error saying: pointer being freed was not allocated

Comment: so I have removed the cleaning mem function. I will analyse the code myself. I am Objective-C programmer, so I also deal with pointer but not on that level.

Comment: Geez, so sorry, I screwed up, @paul.  The memory cleanup code did not belong.  I had originally wrote the code with `strdup` which DOES allocated memory.  `strtok` itself does not allocate memory, but the strings it returns are pointers inside the original string, so you get all kinds of issues.  Languages with managed memory don't have these issues.  It's great to write `split` in Java, Ruby, Python, Perl, etc. because, well, it's built in. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent correctly, you are trying to take a string like `andy:james:john:amy` and arrive at `andy\0james\0john\0amy`.  If this is the case, then your code can be simplified significantly:

```
void splitNameCode(char *code, char *output){
    int loop;
    strncpy(code, output, strlen(code));
    for (loop = 0; output[loop]; loop++){
        if (output[loop] == ':'){ 
            output[loop] = '\0'; // I want to terminate each array in the array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right however I want andy james john amy to be allocated in another array called "output". "output" as you can read in main() function is multidimensional array of char type.